# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError won't go away

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this exception out. Apparently, it can be thrown when a static variable is being initialised or a static block. What I am getting is

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

at the line where I initialise a default value of a variable

```
var prefOctaveIndex = 9
```

as well as in the `onCreate` of my Main Activity where I read from shared preferences to see if it needs to be overwritten

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
prefOctaveIndex = sharedPreferences.getString("octave", "9")?.toInt()!!
```

The exception is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference` in line 12 of

```
fun calculateMonzo(numInput: Long, denInput: Long): MutableList<Long> {
    var num = numInput
    var den = denInput

    val monzo = mutableListOf<Long>(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    for (i in 0..14) while (num % primes[i] == 0L) { // THIS LINE //
        monzo[i]++
        num /= primes[i]
    }
    for (i in 0..14) while (den % primes[i] == 0L) {
        monzo[i]--
        den /= primes[i]
    }
    monzo.add(num)
    monzo.add(den)
    return monzo // length = 17
}
```

and line 10 of this class, which calls the above function.

```
class Ratio private constructor(
        val num: Long,
        val den: Long,
        val monzo: List<Long>
) {
    constructor(monzo: List<Long>) : this(calculateRatio(monzo).first, calculateRatio(monzo).second, monzo)

    constructor(num: Long, den: Long) : this(num, den, calculateMonzo(num, den)) // THIS LINE //

    val sizeInCents: Double = calculateCents(num, den)
    val centDeviation: Pair<String, Double> = calculateCentDeviation(num, den, monzo)
    val notation: Triple<String, String, String> = calculateNotation(monzo)
    val frequency: Double = calculateFrequency(num, den)
    val hd: Double = calculateHD(num, den)
    val bendSibelius = calculateSibeliusBend(centDeviation.second, sizeInCents)
    val bendFinale = calculateFinaleXBend(centDeviation.second, sizeInCents)
}
```

The full stack, in case it is more helpful, but my app is already pretty big so not sure where to even start sharing more code snippets.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.ValsVarsKt.setPrefOctaveIndex(ValsVars.kt:37)
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.FunctionsKt.calculateMonzo(Functions.kt:12)
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.Ratio.<init>(Ratio.kt:10)
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.ValsVarsKt.<clinit>(ValsVars.kt:94)
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.ValsVarsKt.setPrefOctaveIndex(ValsVars.kt:37) 
        at org.plainsound.hejicalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:48) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I don't quite understand, because the app was working fine for weeks.

Comment: Looks like `primes` variable is not initialized. Can you share the code responsible for `primes` initialization.

Comment: Yes! You are right, I am a fool -- it is a `val` of prime numbers that clearly needs to be initialised first in the file before the variables ... thank you!!!

Comment: You welcome, I’m writing it as an answer :)

Comment: This is what happens when you start reorganising your files without thinking...

Comment: Nah don't feel bad, we live for this crap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `primes` variable was not initialized before being used.